# Sort group of elements by content/last Word

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to sort the repeated elements `(.name)` below by the last words of its content. E.g Last name. I'm able to select and wrap the last words in spans respectively but can't get it to be sorted by last name. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(function() {

$('.name').html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/(\w+)$/,'<span class="sort-by">$1</span>');
});

  var $sortPlate = $("#plate");
  $sortPlate.children(".name").children(".sort-by").parent().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
  }).appendTo($sortPlate);

});
```

```css
.name {
    width: 100%;
        font-size: 24px;
    color: green;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.sort-by {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plate">
<div class="name">Deka Junior</div>
<div class="name">Chibueze Okechukwu</div>
<div class="name">Angelina Jolie</div>
<div class="name">Michael Jordan</div>
<div class="name">Chris Okorondu</div>
<div class="name">Angela Zones</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1t2319q4/1/

```
$(function () {

    $('.name').html(function (i, html) {
        return html.replace(/(\w+)$/, '<span class="sort-by">$1</span>');
    });

    var $sortPlate = $("#plate");
    $sortPlate.children(".name").children(".sort-by").parent().detach().sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).text().split(' ')[1].localeCompare($(b).text().split(' ')[1]);
    }).appendTo($sortPlate);

});
```

You almost had it, just split the text on the space and get the last index, which is the last name. Thats the quick and dirty way. You can clean up the code there to make sure there are no errors thrown if there is no space.

Comment: @SleekGeek I would need to see a larger example in fiddle to be sure what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't see how wrapping the last names before loading the page stops that. It simplifies things. Is there a technical reason you can't do it?

Comment: Then I would write out the HTML for the perfect scenario of what I need my javascript to do. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/7msazg03/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\w+/g` , removing calls to `.children()` , `.detach()`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".name").html(function(i, html) {
      var match = html.match(/\w+/g);
      return match[0] + " <span class=sort-by>" + match[1] + "</span>"
    }).get().sort(function(a, b) {
      return $("> .sort-by", a).text().localeCompare($("> .sort-by", b).text());
    }).forEach(function(val) {
      $(val).appendTo(val.parentElement);
    });
})
```

```css
.name {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: green;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.sort-by {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="plate">
  <div class="name">Deka Junior</div>
  <div class="name">Chibueze Okechukwu</div>
  <div class="name">Angelina Jolie</div>
  <div class="name">Michael Jordan</div>
  <div class="name">Chris Okorondu</div>
  <div class="name">Angela Zones</div>
  <div>
```

Comment: If the case is as shown http://jsfiddle.net/7msazg03/1/, How do I get it to work?